# Jenkins github settings without having to provide full repo URL

Tags: jenkins

Going through a tutorial and found that the author has a different view of github and he doesn't have to provide the full URL of the github repo.

[image]

I see a different layout compared to above and need to provide the full github repo URL.

[image]

Trying to figure how to do the same on my jenkins test server. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed exactly same plugin as mentioned in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-admin-guide/github-branch-source-plugin is the plugin used in the tutorial.